# Double sidebar on the left + Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a fluid layout with at least one sidebar at the left. I know how to do this but now I would like to have an expandable sidebar next to the left sidebar. This is an image to explain:

[image]

In the left I have at first a logo and some navigation elements. When you click one the second navigation element I want to show a subnavigation. But how can I do this? Has someone come across an example of this? I really don't know where to start.

For one sidebar:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Navigation 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Navigation 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: should the second sidebar aways be visible? ie even before an item from the first sidebar is clicked? if not, what happens to the main content? should it expand and collapse accordingly?

Comment: The second bar will always be visible! There is always a standard item active in the first bar, so a second bar is always shown.

Comment: Why not an accordion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a small jQuery script that looks up which sub navigation to show based on the links href, which contains the id. Like this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/Y52n9/)**:

```
$(function () {
    $(".main").on("click", "a", function () {
        $(".sub").removeClass("active");
        $($(this).attr("href")).addClass("active");
        console.log($(".sub ul"));
    });
});
```

If you use a HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg" />
            </div>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar main">
                <li class="active"><a href="#sub1">Navigation 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sub2">Navigation 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sub3">Navigation 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul id="sub1" class="nav nav-sidebar sub active">
                <li><a href="#">Subnavigation 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subnavigation 1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subnavigation 1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subnavigation 1.4</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="sub2" class="nav nav-sidebar sub">
                <li><a href="#">Subnavigation 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subnavigation 2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subnavigation 2.3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="sub3" class="nav nav-sidebar sub">
                <li><a href="#">Subnavigation 3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subnavigation 3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subnavigation 3.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subnavigation 3.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subnavigation 3.5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some CSS

```
.logo {
    text-align: center;
}
.logo img {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.sub {
    max-height: 0;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0s;
    background: #fafafa;
}
ul.active {
    max-height: 400px;
    transition: max-height 1s 0.1s;
}
```

Comment: @nielsv The submenu in the demo only contains `href="#"` so nothing will happen if you click the links. If you try and set an external link adress jsFiddle will block it. I have updated the demo with working external links that will open in a new window for submenu1 and internal dummy links for submenu2.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI is perfect for this! http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical
Just style this according to your needs. (Majority of this code was taken from JQuery's documentation)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Vertical Tabs functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
  });
  </script>
  <style>
   //This is the styling that JQuery comes with but can be overridden 
  .ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { display:block; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nav element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Nav element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3"> Nav element 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <h2>Sub nav 1 element </h2>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <h2>Sub nav 2 element</h2>       
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <h2>Sub nav 3 element </h2>
   <h2>Another sub nav 3 element </h2>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Little mistake at `<h2>Sub nav 2 element/h2>`. You've forgot the `<` at the closing `</h2>`.

Answer (score 0):

Being your already using Twitter Bootstrap why not use Stacked Nav-tabs, to show the submenus?

Something like this: (will need to style content to flow after nav) could wrap them in col to be responsive)

```
 <div class="sidebar"> 
   <div class=logo"></div>
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
     <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="tab-content">
   <div id="pane1" class="tab-pane active">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
      <li ><a>Sub Tab 1</a></li>
      <li ><a>Sub Tab 2</a></li>
      <li ><a>Sub Tab 2</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="pane2" class="tab-pane">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
      <li ><a>Sub Tab 1</a></li>
      <li ><a>Sub Tab 2</a></li>
      <li ><a>Sub Tab 2</a></li>
     </ul>
   <div id="pane3" class="tab-pane">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
      <li ><a>Sub Tab 1</a></li>
      <li ><a>Sub Tab 2</a></li>
      <li ><a>Sub Tab 2</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="pane4" class="tab-pane">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
      <li ><a>Sub Tab 1</a></li>
      <li ><a>Sub Tab 2</a></li>
      <li ><a>Sub Tab 2</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```